# Use sed to add space N times

Tags: awk, sed

Pattern:
Mary walks at the park every day with her children

```
sed 's/$/ /'
```

will make it add 1 space at the end (trailing)

I want to add X ($VARIABLE) number of spaces (which comes from RANDOM)

i.e.
VARIABLE='14'
then it will do:

```
sed 's/$/              /'
```

= 14 spaces added at the end.....

Some suggestions how to do that?

I tried to do it adding unicode xA0 but it didn't work

Thanks!

Comment: Since you tagged with awk, are you also thinking in using awk?

Comment: Yes awk would be sufficient also, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
sed "/$/i $(printf '%.0s-' {0..14})" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this post is tagged `awk`, here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk -v "count=$VARIABLE" '{for (n=1;n<=count;n++)$0=$0" "} 1'
```

This solution takes advantage of awk's native ability to define and manipulate arithmetic variables, a capability that `sed` lacks.

#### How it works

- `-v "count=$VARIABLE"`

  This sets the `awk` variable `count` to the value of the shell variable `VARIABLE`.
- `for (n=1;n<=count;n++)$0=$0" "`

  This adds a space to the end of the line `count` times.
- `1`

  This is cryptic shorthand which means print the line.  (The more explicit version would be `{print $0}`.)

Comment: It's best to say `-v count="$VARIABLE"`, since it is `$VARIABLE` what can contain spaces and `-v "count=hello how are you"` wouldn't work

Comment: @fedorqui As a shell command `"v=a b" cmd` and `v="a b" cmd` are different but, here, we are passing a string to `awk`. I just tried `awk` with each & they produced the same result.  Under what circumstances would you expect there to be a difference between those two?  (Remember that the shell does quote removal before passing the argument on to `awk`.)

Comment: You are right! I somehow thought that  `awk -v "var=hello you" 'BEGIN{print var}'` would just print `hello`, whereas after testing I see it performs exactly the same as `-v var="hello you"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSpace=15

sed "1 {x
:pre
   s/^/ /
   / \\{${NSpace}\\}/ !b pre
   x
   }
G;s/\n//" YourFile
```

posix sed version. More for fun than to be efficient compare to awk, perl or even bash script

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl` try this:

`perl -pe '$char=" "; $n=14; $str="$char"x$n; s/$/$str/'`

In action (for better visualization I am setting $char to ".") :

```
perl -pe '$char="."; $n=14; $str="$char"x$n; s/$/$str/' <<< 'abc' 
abc..............
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo ok |
    perl -Mutf8 -CS -pe 's/$/sprintf "%s", (chr oct "0x2009") x (int(rand 10)) . "x"/e'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
ok        x
```

piped with `od -c` :

```
0000000   o   k 342 200 211 342 200 211   x  \n
0000012
```

Comment: Added handling of RANDOM

Comment: Does it fit your needs ?

Answer (score 0):

Bash: taking advantage of printf's `*` width specifier

```
$ n=15
$ printf -v spaces '%*s' $n " "
$ echo ">$spaces<"
>               <
```

Similarly with awk

```
$ spaces2=$(awk -v n=$n 'BEGIN {printf "%*s", n, " "}')
$ echo ">$spaces2<"
>               <
```

You can then use this string of spaces in your sed call (or decide that you don't need sed at all, that part is unclear)

Answer (score 0):

My awk solution looks more like this:

```
awk -v num=14 '{printf("%s%"num"s\n", $0, "")}' input.txt
```

Of course, it might need to be adapted if you have funny line endings.

It works by using a `printf` format that has a second field with a fixed size, a size which is specified using the `num` variable inserted into the awk script by the `-v` option.  If you use this, be sure that `num` is actually a number, or you're break your format.

Comment: FYI you can write `awk -v num=14 '{printf("%s%*s\n", $0, num, "")}' input.txt` and it won't behave quite so wackily when given a non-numeric num since awk is then looking for a number to use in the format and not just any old string as part of the formatting string itself.